# Making Comments Editable?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, comments

How would I make my WordPress Comments Editable?

I tried using an Ajax plugin that take them to another screen, but it's not as nice as I would like. For example, I just want it to re-open the initial comment box and allow them to edit their comment for at least 30 minutes after a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best plugin I've found is [Editable Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/editable-comments/).

[image: Editable Comments backend]

[image: Editable Comments in action]

Comment: Have you tried any other plugins that let people login using a FB, Gmail, Twitter or other Social account?

Comment: @dreamgrowers: have not, sorry!